# Behavior of electron beam in magnetic field?

Tags: particle-physics

I am a little confused by this concept.

Say you have a electron gun that fires a beam of electrons so that it looks something like this: [image]

The right hand rule doesn't work on this setup, right? Because the electron beam is emitting... electrons, you would need to use the left hand rule, or reverse the direction of whatever you get from the right hand rule?

By using the "right hand rule" with my left hand, I was able to get consistent results, but I am just wondering, is that an acceptable/logically sound way to find the direction of the force of the magnetic field on the stream of electrons?

Answer (score 2):

The method that "always" works for me - using the vector math expression for the force:

$$\mathbf{F} = q~ \mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{B}$$

The cross product follows the right hand rule - thumb along the first vector (velocity, pointing up), index along the second vector (B field, pointing towards you), vector product points along the middle finger (to the right). The charge of the electron is negative, so you need to flip the vector. That makes the magnetic force point away from the center.

I conclude that there is a problem with the diagram. The B field appears to have be drawn the wrong way (or it's a proton gun, not an electron gun)...

Comment: Right, so the magnetic field should point towards the center of the diagram? (thanks)

Comment: towards the center of the circle, I mean

Comment: The magnetic field is drawn to be out of the plane (towards you) using the arrow convention: cross = in (you see the tail of the arrow), dot is out (you see the tip of the arrow). But in that case the magnetic FORCE (not field) on an electron should point OUT from the center of the circle; yet it needs to point IN. There is something wrong.